# Pybind11 module not working on deployment to heroku

Tags: heroku, boost, cmake, pybind11

I'm trying to deploy an app built in dash to heroku. This app uses simulation code written in c++, which is imported as a python module using pybind 11. When I upload the compiled code I get the following error message when looking at the heroku logs

```
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /app/simulation_module_name.so)
```

I presume that this means that code compiled with pybind11 on my machine is not compatible with the machines I am trying to deploy to.

My next attempt was the build the module directly on the heroku servers using setup.py and cmake, but this requires functions from the boost libraries, which are >1GB and so I can't upload them over git. I also tried uploading only the relevant boost header files, with the relevant cmake, such that

```
set(include_dir "lib")
set(source_dir "src")
# Boost
list(APPEND include_dirs ${include_dir}/boost)

set(header_files
    ${include_dir}/boost/math/tools/minima.hpp
    ${include_dir}/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp
    ${include_dir}/boost/math/tools/roots.hpp
    ${include_dir}/boost/math/tools/tuple.hpp
    )
# Pybind11
add_subdirectory(${include_dir}/pybind11)
include_directories(${source_dir} ${include_dirs})
pybind11_add_module(simulation_module_name ${header_files} "${source_dir}/simulation_module.cpp")
```

and

```
#include "minima.hpp"
#include "constants.hpp"
#include "roots.hpp"
```

But I received the error:

```
fatal error: minima.hpp: No such file or directory
remote:             #include "minima.hpp"
remote:                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Are any of these three options possible?

1. Get the heroku dynos to run the pybind11 module I compiled on my machine
2. Upload the installed boost library (over the size limit) and compile on the heroku server
3. Use the header functions and cmake and compile on the heroku server (as I have tried but failed to do here)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, how?

Comment: @Squeezie I installed the math parts of boost via the Dockerfile (libboost-math-dev), and then removed the set(header_files) command from the cmakelists file. Make sure you get your directory structure sorted, as I also ran into this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780558/docker-with-cmake-error-forcetorelativepath-failed

Answer (score 0):

> Get the heroku dynos to run the pybind11 module I compiled on my machine

To do this, you will need to compile the shared library on a linux version with (at least) the same or older version of GLIBC. One possibility is to compile your binaries in a docker image matching or predating whatever linux distro is used by Heroku. Alternatively, I would also suggest looking at the `manylinux10` or `manylinux14` images [here](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux), which are designed specifically for solving this cross-distro build/sharing problem and include many of the necessary build tools.